# debug message: before or after?

Tags: logging

Suppose I'm doing an operation and there are some reasons to communicate that I'm doing it:

- debugging
- inform the user about slow operation

for example:

```
cout << "Starting query" << endl;
do_query();
```

but I can also do:

```
do_query();
cout << "Query done" << endl;
```

yes, of course there is a third solution

```
cout << "Staring query...";
do_query();
cout << " [DONE]";
```

there are some better solutions / guidelines?

Comment: Obviously, Third one is better.

Comment: yes, but it's verbose. Suppose to choose between the first two

Comment: Actually, I would say first two contain incomplete information. -- The first one doesn't inform about successful completion. And the second one doesn't inform even if its started or not, when there is no log saying "Query done".

Answer (score 1):

I'd do both, personally. If you were to choose only one then I think the user would be more interested to know why they are waiting patiently.

Comment: If you're worried about being too verbose, and do_query doesn't output any text, you could just miss out the `<< endl` in the "pre-" message